# How to base on the counted values and separately insert the records with using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my first time to ask question in here.

For example...

```
Table A
ID        COUNT
---------------
123       4
124       3
125       1
```

I want to base on the table a COUNT values and separating the count records to '1' in Table B with below format with using SQL statement only(without PL/SQL). Is it possible?

```
Table B
ID        COUNT
---------------
123       1
123       1
123       1
123       1
124       1
124       1
124       1
125       1
```

I know it is easy to do if using PL/SQL, but if there any way to solve below problem with using SQL statement only? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,1
FROM YOURTABLE
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= COUNT1
   AND PRIOR id = id
   AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c06f81/1)